# Check if string is in an array of objects VueJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a text field where a user can input the value and then `on click` of a button push the value inside an array. The value i want to test for is the `uniqueID`. So let's say if the user inputs multiple values including comma or white spaces and one of them matches the `uniqueId` in the existing array. Then i get an alert.

I tried using `some` but that didn't quite work. Not sure what i am doing wrong.

Here is a sample [pen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/ZEbprrg?editors=1111)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      myArray: [{
          title: "Sam",
          age: 36,
          uniqueId: "GHTR435"
        },
        {
          title: "Max",
          age: 44,
          uniqueId: "MLKT432"
        }
      ],
      inputField: "",
      inputArray: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    createArray() {
      if (this.myArray.some((el) => el.uniqueID === this.inputField)) {
        alert("Heyy!!!!");
      } else {
        this.inputArray.push(this.inputField.trim().replace(/, +/g, ","));
        console.log(this.inputArray);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout justify-center>
        <v-flex xs6>
          <v-text-field solo v-model="inputField"></v-text-field>
          <v-btn @click="createArray">Click Me</v-btn>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: if (this.myArray.some((el) => this.inputField.split(/[, ]/g).includes(el.uniqueID))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (this.myArray.some((el) => this.inputField.split(/[, ]/g).includes(el.uniqueID))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your condition. It should be

```
this.myArray.some((el) => el.uniqueId /* <-- "d" instead of "D" */ === this.inputField)
```

Comment: but if i input something like GHTR435, TGFHD322.  It still works, since these are multiple values and some seems to work only for one value.